# lazy Grid view gets refresh while scrolling in android

Tags: gridview, lazy-loading, android-gridview

### When I run this code images are loded one by one. when i scroll the page the image position gets changed please help me to solve this problem

An array of url is passed to the image_grid constructor .
By the use of async task the url is processed and it returns the bitmap.

## image_grid.java

```
public class image_grid extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private final String[] url;
    public image_grid(Context applicationContext, String[] url) {
        mContext = applicationContext;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.url = url;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return url.length;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View grid;
        if (convertView == null) {
            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.assignment_image_grid, parent,
                    false);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }
        ImageView image = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        TextView text = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) grid.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        text.setText("Hai : " + position);
        System.out.println("url[position]" + url[position]);
        new DownloadImageTask(url[position], pb, image).execute();
        return grid;
    }
    public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        String url = null;
        ProgressBar pb = null;
        ImageView imageview = null;
        public DownloadImageTask(String url, ProgressBar pb, ImageView imageview) {
            super();
            this.url = url;
            this.pb = pb;
            this.imageview = imageview;
        }
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... pb_and_images) {
            return getBitmapDownloaded(url);
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(result);
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        /** This function downloads the image and returns the Bitmap **/
        private Bitmap getBitmapDownloaded(String url) {
            System.out.println("String URL " + url);
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(url)
                        .getContent());
                return bitmap;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this class

```html
public class ImageLoader {
    
    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService; 
    
    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }
    
    final int stub_id = R.drawable.loading;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }
        
    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }
    
    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);
        
        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;
        
        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);
            
            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }
            
            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }
    
    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    }
    
    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }
    
    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    
    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

for storing as disk cache

```html
  
public class FileCache {
  
    private File cacheDir;
  
    public FileCache(Context context){
        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"TempImages");
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }
  
    public File getFile(String url){
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        return f;
  
    }
  
    public void clear(){
        File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
        if(files==null)
            return;
        for(File f:files)
            f.delete();
    }
  
}
```

utils class

```html
 
public class Utils {
    public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
    {
        final int buffer_size=1024;
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
            for(;;)
            {
              int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
              if(count==-1)
                  break;
              os.write(bytes, 0, count);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
    }
}
```

memory cache class

```html
public class MemoryCache {
    private Map<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> cache=Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>());
  
    public Bitmap get(String id){
        if(!cache.containsKey(id))
            return null;
        SoftReference<Bitmap> ref=cache.get(id);
        return ref.get();
    }
  
    public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
        cache.put(id, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
    }
  
    public void clear() {
        cache.clear();
    }
}
```

use it like this inside your adapter

```
public ImageLoader imageLoader;
```

inside constructor of adapter

```
imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());
```

and inside getview

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage("url of image", imageview);
```